# Reg Exp in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to fill in a text-box two number separated by "-"  example 5-3  23-12
how do I perform the check(reg exp) for those numbers and the separator all together?

```
<form id="myForm"  method="post">
<input type="text" name="entered"><br>
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="buttonLogic()"><br>
<select id="selector">
</select>
</form>
```

Need some help just for the RegExp.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an input element I suppose. Use a regular expression on the value of the text-box.
For example, if your input has the id 'box',

```
var boxValue = document.getElementById('box').value.match(/(\d+)-(\d+)/)
```

you will get an array with the:
 - box-value 
 - first number
 - second number

Comment: You shouldn't assume he's using jQuery, there is no mention of it in the question

Comment: helped a lot! thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this regex : `/^(\d+)-(\d+)$/`